# Spring Boot - Lot of invalid requests and Socket accept failed java.io.IOException: Too many open files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ioexception

I have running machine with `Spring (Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE)` application. Recently I'm receiving a lot of warnings in my log file:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: null; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

I've checked with `tcpdump` and a lot of request don't have body (empty/null) or have incorrect body e.g. `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00speed":"23.3","user_id":106312}`

The biggest problem is that after some time I'm starting to receiving exceptions in my app:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket accept failed

java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:443)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`ulimit -n` says that limit of open files is set to `65536` so I think it's big enough.

I'm assuming that receiving big amount of invalid requests causes IOException but why? And what should I do to avoid it and fix it?

Comment: So, do you for some reasons keep client connections live ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636676/error-in-tomcat-too-many-open-files

Comment: ulimit is system-wide resource, so it limits handle to files on system (overall). Try checking process limit. Thats in link above.

Comment: @Antoniossss but I don't have any ```Stream``` in my application, I only have rest endpoints to receive data from clients

Comment: Check that limit. Maybe you are leaking resource handles somewhere (not on rest endpoint acceptor)

Comment: Could be worth upgrading Spring Boot to the latest 1.5.X release if possible and trying to verify in case it was fixed in the many bugfixes

Comment: @Antoniossss I have checked with ```cat /proc/PID/limits``` and there is ```Max open files 4096``` but ```ls -l /proc/PID/fd | wc -l``` says that current is ```124``` so it is way below limit but I will monitor if this number change after some time

Comment: Ye try to do that.Exception says you are hitting that limit (obviously) but now you know, that you dont have FFFF limit as you assumed in the first place ;) Double chekc if you are not reading files, keeping socket open or idk whatever that might be as file in linux.

Comment: it's quite hard to investigate, but do you see any strange in access log and at the same time, which strange request cause the error?

Comment: I am not so sure about IO Exception but sounds like similar to DDOS attack. Api and clients have a contract on headers and type of requests for communication between each other. If they defer we can treat them as rogue clients and should create a patch for clients or block IP of these  rogue clients to not send invalid requests.  On the other side we can try reduce socket connection time to see if that can help.

Comment: @AnveshVejandla it's not DDOS, server works in internal network. Invalid requests are caused by malfunction of devices which send requests or very poor GSM signal (devices are connected by GSM modem). I can't block them.

Comment: @Antoniossss today I have 170 opened files so it increased a little bit, maybe after few days or even weeks it hits the limit and that's how i get these errors. But I'm not sure how to verify what sockets/files are opened and why (or why aren't they closing properly)

Comment: @huy in which access log should I check?

Comment: Are you sure there is no file access in your bussiness logic or something?

Comment: @user3626048 are you able to validate requests or what steps have you taken to prevent invalid requests? May be something in headers you can use to validate invalid requests. When poor quality then requests might not be well formed.

Comment: Please include **all** IO-related source code in your question. Your socket not opening because there are too many open files is just a symptom, the actual root of the problem can be anywhere. For example: something as simple as `Files.list()` ***will*** leave an open file descriptor unless you explicitly `close` it.

Comment: Try checking the output for `ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head` to identify if any of the process is consuming the resources. (we have similar issue and were able to zero down using this - so it might help you as well)

Comment: @Antoniossss ```ls -l /proc/PID/fd``` shows that about 95% of elements are like ```socket:[2759091]``` or ```pipe:[16453]``` etc. (only different numbers) or ```/dev/random```, the rest 5% are jvm's .jar files or two my log files (handled by ```Spring``` logger). I don't have any part of code where files are opened manually

Comment: @LuisG. I don't have any part of code where files are opened manually, only two log files handled by ```Spring``` logger

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond I've tried that but result is only my ```java -jar MYAPP.jar```, ```/usr/sbin/collectd -C /etc/``` and few ```postgres``` related processes (but with small memory and cpu usage)

Comment: Can't really help you if you don't show us your code. For all we know you could be doing `while(true) socket.open();` ^^ It might even _not_ be your code's problem but something else in your system using up all resources, but how would we know if we cannot see the code?

Comment: Maybe you are using sockets directly (as client or server) and those are not closed somewhere. Its kind of hard to belive that your application server is leaking resources - nevertheless thats not impossible.

Comment: @Antoniosss on my server I have only RESTful API and Websockets (but websockets logs debug info every few minutes and shows no pending connections). There are no direct socket connection. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076737/springboot-tomcatembeddedservletcontainer-keepalivetimeout-not-working do you think it might be related to my issue?

Comment: Since there is nothing else to get a grip on, give it a try.

Comment: Did you solved it? If not, have you tried going to `/etc/security/limits.conf` and adding increasing the number of possible documents that can be opened at one time? Also, are you reading from properties files? You could be opening the same file several times for some reason. [Linux conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use web socket with spring boot. You can listen on only 65535 port maximum, you can't exceed this amount of value on a machine. You should check if you close properly your sockets.