# How to resolve the error java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: grails, jmeter

I have been doing load testing for my REST APIs using JMeter.

I am getting the following error when hit with 1000 concurrent users:

```
Too many open files. Stacktrace follows:
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:397)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:460)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1017)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:476)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:390)
```

My server tries to hit another REST API to get the data and process it and finally return a JSON response.

How do I increase the number of open files in Linux?

Following is the call I am making to another server

```
Map getResponse(Map data, String url){
    HTTPBuilder httpBuilder = new HTTPBuilder(url);
    httpBuilder.request(Method.POST, JSON) {
        headers.'Authorization' = AppConfig.config.appKey;
        headers.'Content-type' = 'application/json'
        body = data
        response.success = { resp, reader ->
            return reader as Map;
        }
        response.failure = { response, reader ->
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux help?

Comment: Looks like files are not closed. Post your code here.

Comment: Probably you created a lot of Sockets but did not  close() them. I think default maximum for open files and or sockets on Linux machines is 1024.

Comment: @akhil_mittal Well yeah... that's kind of the point of load testing. The program is *supposed* to have a thousand open sockets at any given time.

Comment: [How to solve java.net.SocketException: Too many files open](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37605213/6120248)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have certainly open the maximum number of open file/sockets. The maximum number of open files or sockets on Linux machines is 1024. by default. You need to change that. You can refer this [java.net.SocketException Too many open files](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311083018/http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/KB/java.net.SocketException+Too+many+open+files)

You can use below query to check from your terminal to get maximum number of allowed open files

```
ulimit -n
```

From [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12007):

> What's happening is that the underlying sockets aren't being closed,
> and eventually the JVM bumps into the system's per-process limit on
> open file descriptors.
>
> The right solution would be to make the sockets close at the Right
> Time (which I guess is when, or shortly after, the server has closed
> its end of the connection).  That seems hard with HttpURLConnection.
> It's all very confused:

> - disconnect() just seems to close it immediately -- or not;
>   the Javadocs are intentionally vague about what it actually
>   does, and especially when it does it.
> - close() might be the right choice.  The Evaluation section of
>   Java bug #4147525 says: "... call close() on the input and/or
>   output stream. This will correctly result in the underlying
>   socket being closed when you aren't doing keepalive
>   connections and will correctly cache and reuse keepalive
>   connections (and which will timeout and close themselves
>   after a short time anyway)."
> - But maybe not.  Bug #4142971 says: "Calling the close()
>   methods has no effect one way or the other on whether the
>   underlying HTTP connection is persistent."
>
> Failing a clear answer, perhaps the HttpURLConnection objects could be
> added to a list, and all disconnected at once at the end of the test
> run.  That'd still limit the total size of the run, but at least the
> lost descriptors wouldn't accumulate between runs.
>
> **Maybe the real answer is to give up on HttpURLConnection, and instead
> use the HTTP Client from Jakarta Commons.  Someone suggested that in
> connection with a different problem (bug
> `#4143518`).**

Comment: This is bang on. No matter how I closed and cleaned up my connections using `HttpsUrlConnection`, I was always running into "Too many open files." I switched over to `OkHttp` and it worked nearly out of the box. I'm assuming now that it's a bug in `HttpsUrlConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

**"java.net.SocketException: Too many files** open"can be seen any Java Server application e.g. Tomcat, Weblogic, WebSphere etc, with client connecting and disconnecting frequently.

[You can find out how to solve **"java.net.SocketException: Too many files open"** here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605213/6120248)

Comment: It can happend with Netty as well with kotlin