# Play Framework calling controller causes Too many open files error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.3

We use Play Framework 2.3.4 with Java and Hibernate/Spring.
It runs fine in production for a couple of days and then suddenly this happens:

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:460)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:520)
    at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.configureSocket(StandardSocketFactory.java:134)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:205)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
    ... 75 more
```

Then some of these:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/psldata-api-1.0.0/app/controllers/StatsController.java (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at play.utils.PlayIO$.readFileAsString(PlayIO.scala:63)
    at play.api.Application$$anon$1$$anonfun$input$2.apply(Application.scala:302)
    at play.api.Application$$anon$1$$anonfun$input$2.apply(Application.scala:302)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.api.Application$$anon$1.input(Application.scala:302)
    at play.api.PlayException$ExceptionSource.interestingLines(PlayException.java:81)
    at views.html.defaultpages.devError$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(devError.template.scala:157)
    at views.html.defaultpages.devError$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(devError.template.scala:142)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at views.html.defaultpages.devError$.apply(devError.template.scala:142)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$devError$1$1.apply(GlobalSettings.scala:141)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$devError$1$1.apply(GlobalSettings.scala:141)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:147)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.play$core$j$JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$super$onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:319)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:316)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
```

And then some of these:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/psldata-api-1.0.0/app/controllers/APIController.java (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at play.utils.PlayIO$.readFileAsString(PlayIO.scala:63)
    at play.api.Application$$anon$1$$anonfun$input$2.apply(Application.scala:302)
    at play.api.Application$$anon$1$$anonfun$input$2.apply(Application.scala:302)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.api.Application$$anon$1.input(Application.scala:302)
    at play.api.PlayException$ExceptionSource.interestingLines(PlayException.java:81)
    at views.html.defaultpages.devError$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(devError.template.scala:157)
    at views.html.defaultpages.devError$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(devError.template.scala:142)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at views.html.defaultpages.devError$.apply(devError.template.scala:142)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$devError$1$1.apply(GlobalSettings.scala:141)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$devError$1$1.apply(GlobalSettings.scala:141)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:147)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.play$core$j$JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$super$onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:36)
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:319)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:316)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
```

So basically everything further gives this error, until I restart the application. It seems like a memory leak or something is not closed properly, but I have no idea what it could be. Has anybody had this error before? Thanks.

Comment: `lsof | grep <play-java-pid> | more` and you will see all opened by play proccess files.

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your file paths that you're using Linux, which has a limit on the number of files and sockets you can open, which is usually setup to 1024.  You can count the number of open file descriptors using the `lsof` command.  The issue you're getting is that you're going over the limit.  You can run `lsof -u <playuser> | wc -l` to check this.  You can see the limits you currently have setup per user in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (for at least Ubuntu and RedHat).

If you've got a legitimate reason to have a lot of file handlers or sockets open, then you can increase the limit using the `ulimit` command (`ulimit -n` will set the limit to the maximum number the system will support).  But if you don't, and you do have a leak, this will just postpone the inevitable crash.

If there isn't a legitimate reason to have so many file handler and sockets open, I would check to make sure you're closing any sockets you create, and make sure you're closing all of those `FileInputStreams`.  Make sure you're closing them properly in 'finally' blocks.  Without seeing your controller code, I can't be sure it's a problem with closing the `FileInputStreams`, but I recommend checking them.

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207301) with a bit more detail on socket limits.