# Spring integration Sftp inbound adapter getting unknown host exception intermittently

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

How do I gracefully log the error message generated by my spring integration sftp inbound adapter ? I don’t see any advice object configuration for it. Plus is there a way to get rid of intermittent session unknown host exception. This happens every other week.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.util.PoolItemNotAvailableException: Failed to obtain pooled item
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:447)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:85)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:200)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:211)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:181)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:303)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:398)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: XXXXXXXXXXXX.com
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:294)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: XXXXXXXXXXX.com
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: May we see a stack trace on the matter? Just to be sure what code is involved.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: See if this discussion helps you somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013658/unknownhostexception-occures-when-connecting-sftp-using-java