Sending lots of GET requests in Java (Spring) application
I am working on a Spring Boot application. I'm trying to send around 3.5k GET requests to an endpoint, however, when using the following code, it sends the java.io.IOException: too many concurrent streams error.
    public void scrapeEventsForDateRange(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        for (LocalDate date = endDate; !date.isBefore(startDate); date = date.minusDays(1)) {
            fetchAndSaveEventsForDateAsync(date, false);
        }
    }

    public void runStartup() {
        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate startDate = currentDate.minusYears(10);
        scrapeEventsForDateRange(startDate, currentDate);
    }

   private void fetchAndSaveEventsForDateAsync(LocalDate date, boolean live) {
        String formattedDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        String url = "HIDDEN ENDPOINT" + formattedDate;

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .build();
        client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenAcceptAsync(response -> {
                    if (live) {
                        processEventsResponseLive(response);
                    } else {
                        processEventsResponse(response);
                    }
                })
                .exceptionally(ex -> {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                });
    }


I tried many ways, such as Semaphore's - but those are very slow. I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this. I'm using java.net.http.HttpClient for the requests.

Related: discussion about being able to handle this more nicely - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8225647, regarding use of semaphore - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57359328/1466267

You can try to switch from HTTP/2 back to HTTP/1.1 like this:
HttpClient
    .newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
    .build()

The only downside is that it will create a new worker thread for every connection. But you can limit number of worker threads if you setup a ThreadFactory and pass it to HttpClient via ExecutorService.
