# JMeter Ubuntu: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: file, sockets, ubuntu, jmeter, response

Once JMeter script with 5000 values in CSV file is executed with `Synchronization Timer`, Response data in `View Results in Tree` shows following error:

**`java.net.SocketException: Too many open files`**

I could not find the satisfactory answer yet on google.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you opening that file 5000 times? That's bad approach. You could load your values just once and create some Beanshell logic to use that values as you need...

Comment: No, just once. CSV contains 5000 Email values.

Answer (score 3):

Increase the number of open file handles or file descriptors per process.

You can use command `ulimit -a` to find out how many open file handles per process is allowed.

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size        (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size         (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size             (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                    (-n) 1024
pipe size          (512 bytes, -p) 10
stack size            (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time             (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes            (-u) 2048
virtual memory        (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

You can see that, open files (-n) 1024, which means only 1024 open file handles per process is allowed. If your Java program exceeds this limit, it will throw `java.net.SocketException: Too many files open` error.

See these threads [I/O exception (java.net.SocketException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656458/java-net-socketexception-too-many-open-files/37605213#37605213) and [java.net.SocketException: Too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656458/java-net-socketexception-too-many-open-files/37605213#37605213).

Comment: I used root to login and executed these commands. But when I switched to other ordinary user, I found the open files number  was the original value. Could I configure the number of open file handles for all users?